# How to abort a running program in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, process, abort

Sometimes after calling a function (which takes some 30 odd minutes to finish), you realize that you did something wrong and want to **stop the program**.

How do you do that in MATLAB?

What I do is **shutdown MATLAB completely and restart**. I think there would be a way to **abort the execution** of the function instead.

Anybody know what that is?

Comment: In case you run into the situation where `CTRL + C` does not do the trick, this thread may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791144/how-to-stop-a-running-script-in-matlab

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> usually does the trick, although [sometimes it has been known to run into snags](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-188VX/index.html).

Comment: I've often found that adding a drawnow() call in a loop helps Matlab catch Ctrl+C.