# how to stop a running script in Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab

I write a long running script in Matlab, e.g.

```
tic;
d = rand(5000);
[a,b,c] = svd(d);
toc;
```

It seems running forever. Becasue I press F5 in the editor window. So I cannot press C-Break to stop in the Matlab console.

I just want to know how to stop the script. I am current use Task Manager to kill Matlab, which is really silly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Matlab help says this-
For M-files that run a long time, or that call built-ins or MEX-files that run a long time, Ctrl+C does not always effectively stop execution. Typically, this happens on Microsoft Windows platforms rather than UNIX[1]  platforms. If you experience this problem, you can help MATLAB break execution by including a drawnow, pause, or getframe function in your M-file, for example, within a large loop. Note that Ctrl+C might be less responsive if you started MATLAB with the -nodesktop option.

So I don't think any option exist. This happens with many matlab functions that are complex. Either we have to wait or don't use them!.

Answer (score 5):

If ctrl+c doesn't respond right away because your script is too long/complex, hold it.

The break command doesn't run when matlab is executing some of its deeper scripts, and either it won't log a ctrl sequence in the buffer, or it clears the buffer just before or just after it completes those pieces of code. In either case, when matlab returns to execute more of your script, it will recognize that you are holding ctrl+c and terminate.

For longer running programs, I usually try to find a good place to provide a status update and I always accompany that with some measure of time using tic and toc. Depending on what I am doing, I might use run time, segment time, some kind of average, etc...

For really long running programs, I found this to be exceptionally useful 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16649-send-text-message-to-cell-phone/content/send_text_message.m

but it looks like they have some newer functions for this too.

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB doesn't respond to Ctrl-C while executing a mex implemented function such as svd. Also when MATLAB is allocating big chunk of memory it doesn't respond. A good practice is to always run your functions for small amount of data, and when all test passes run it for actual scale. When time is an issue, you would want to analyze how much time each segment of code runs as well as their rough time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider having multiple matlab sessions. Keep the main session window (the pretty one with all the colours, file manager, command history, workspace, editor etc.) for running stuff that you know will terminate.

Stuff that you are experimenting with, say you are messing with ode suite and you get lots of warnings: matrix singular, because you altered some parameter and didn't predict what would happen, run in a separate session:

```
dos('matlab -automation -r &')
```

You can kill that without having to restart the whole of Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I adopted--for use with java code, but the concept is the same with mexFunctions, just messier--is to return a FutureValue and then loop while FutureValue.finished() or whatever returns true. The actual code executes in another thread/process. Wrapping a try,catch around that and a FutureValue.cancel() in the catch block works for me.

In the case of mex functions, you will need to return somesort of pointer (as an int) that points to a struct/object that has all the data you need (native thread handler, bool for complete etc). In the case of a built in mexFunction, your mexFunction will most likely need to call that mexFunction in the separate thread. Mex functions are just DLLs/shared objects after all.

PseudoCode

```
FV = mexLongProcessInAnotherThread();
try
  while ~mexIsDone(FV);
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); %pause has a memory leak
    drawnow; %allow stdout/err from mex to display in command window
  end
catch
  mexCancel(FV);
end
```

Comment: This seems like it is something that I need. However, this function called mexCancel, how would that one look?

Comment: @patrik That depends entirely on what your long process looks like. Essentially, cancel, isdone, and longprocess would all need to be written in c to work together, exported to a dll, and then mex-functions written to call those functions. It's not easy nor clean nor is there going to be general code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems kind of discouraging, but anyway, if this would be achieved it is certainly a beautyful solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Task Manager, I'll guess you're using Windows. Assuming you're running your script within the editor, if you aren't opposed to quitting the editor at the same time as quitting the running program, the keyboard shortcut to end a process is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

(By which I mean press the 'Alt' and 'F4' keys on your keyboard simultaneously.)

Alternatively, as mentioned in other answers,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

should also work, but will not quit the editor.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your matlab on linux, you can terminate the matlab by command in linux consule.
first you should find the PID number of matlab by this code:

top

then you can use this code to kill matlab:
kill

example:
kill 58056

Answer (score -3):

To add on:

you can insert a time check within a loop with intensive or possible deadlock, ie.

```
:
section_toc_conditionalBreakOff;
:
```

where within this section

```
if (toc > timeRequiredToBreakOff)     % time conditional break off
      return;
      % other options may be:                         
      % 1. display intermediate values with pause;
      % 2. exit;                           % in some cases, extreme : kill/ quit matlab
end
```