# Is it possible to stop or interrupt a code in MATLAB if a condition is reached and end the simulation of the program code ?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to stop or interrupt a code in MATLAB if a condition is reached and end the simulation of the program code ? eg I have a loop that involves calculating a parameter and the moment the value becomes a complex no. I would like my code to stop executing and return the value of the counter at which the parameter value became complex.

Comment: Take a look to http://scrolls.mafgani.net/2007/03/matlab-interrupting-function-execution/ and to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791144/how-to-stop-a-running-script-in-matlab.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to exit your script, you can use this:

```
if complex(parameter)
    disp(counter);
    return;
end
```

If you want to exit a function and return the value of the counter to the caller, you can use this:

```
if complex(parameter)
    return(counter)
end
```

If you just want to break out of a loop, use this:

```
for ...
    if complex(parameter)
        break;
    end
end
print(counter)
```

Comment: `exit` will not only exit the script, but will quit MATLAB itself.