# How to break matlab script execution?

Tags: matlab, interruption

How to break Matlab script execution? `Ctrl-C` does not work, probably because of using `waitforbuttonpress` inside `catch`:

```
while 1
    try
        waitforbuttonpress
    catch err
    end
end
```

Comment: `Ctrl-C` doesn't always stops scripts. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791144/how-to-stop-a-running-script-in-matlab).

Comment: Also consider putting in a [feature request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) with The MathWorks. Mathematica can abort running code with no problem by simply quitting and restarting the kernel. In 2013 when one can't abort a running script on a modern 64-bit multicore machine, it's a failure of software architecture. Requiring users is to put in special code is no solution.